# nxt-py no backends error

Tags: python, nxt, pyusb

i am trying to run one of the example scripts for nxt py library using pyusb. whenever i try to run the examples i get the following error:

```
USB module unavailable, not searching there
Bluetooth module unavailable, not searching there
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Documents and Settings\*\Desktop\nxt-python-2.2.1\examples\mary.py", line
15, in <module>
b = nxt.locator.find_one_brick()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nxt\locator.py", line 112, in find_one_brick
for s in find_bricks(host, name, silent, method):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nxt\locator.py", line 80, in find_bricks
raise NoBackendError("No selected backends are available! Did you install the comm
modules?")
NoBackendError: No selected backends are available! Did you install the comm modules?
```

i have no idea how to fix this and i was wondering if there was any other way than just switching to bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

USB and Bluetooth are unavailable. You need to install python modules to be able to run examples. 
Here is installation guide, 
[choose your operating system](http://code.google.com/p/nxt-python/wiki/Installation).

For me (mac os x) works only fantomusb. Also I needed to set attributes for brick locator to find it trought fantomusb.

```
b = nxt.locator.find_one_brick(name="NXT", strict=True, method=nxt.locator.Method(bluetooth=False, fantomusb=True, fantombt=False, usb=False))
```